# Visual Studio 2012 FTP Website Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I used to be able to open an FTP website in Visual Studio 2012 until recently when it stopped working correctly.  I can connect to my server using FTP and I get the full folder list of my servers websites, but attempting to open any file in any of the folders (asp.x,aspx.vb etc) Visual Studio just hangs - has anyone else experienced this, and if so how was it resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I've installed Visual Studio updates (through visual studio update checker) and everything works fine now